# Android, using Toast inside onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, toast

I am trying to make a toast display some text given certain conditions inside an onClickListener. The app won´t run in the simulator, and I get the following error: "void cannot be converted to Toast"

I have searched around, and find several similar problems and solutions on this forum, but none of them applies completely to my problem. The others haven´t used the correct context in the statement, but I really mean that I do. (The name of the javafile (context) is: "Case1Activity") Can anyone help me with this?
I have simplified the code a bit:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button1Pushed == false){
                count++;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Case1Activity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove this `Toast toast =`

Comment: The method **show()** returns nothing.So it is not correct with **Toast toast ==**.

Comment: Check below how to eat this Toast

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do it without assignment statement

```
Toast.makeText(Case1Activity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

apply it as.

```
Toast.makeText(Case1Activity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use assignment operator then you can use below code

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Dear Friend check below before eating Toast,

**Your Toast (Incompatible types error) :**

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Case1Activity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Normal Case (Standard Use):**

```
Toast.makeText(Case1Activity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

**Special Case (if you need reference of Toast):**

```
 View toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are doing this in the right order!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

because here **".show()"** method is -

public void show () which 
shows the view for the specified duration.

Thanks