# How do I display a Toast in a setOnClickListener?

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a Toast when the user clicks on the Play button. But `makeText` is red in my code, and it won't run. Where am I turning wrong?

Here is the Java code:

```
    // Find the View that shows the play_a button
    ImageView play_a = findViewById(R.id.play_a);

    // Set a click listener on that View
    play_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when play_a is clicked on.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, Play doesn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
```

Is the problem that I need to override `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, using Toast inside onClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437997/android-using-toast-inside-onclicklistener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `onClick` function.

```
play_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry, Play doesn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` keyword in **makeText** refers to *anonymous-inner-class* of type `OnClickListener`. You need to change it to pass the `Context`.

For example: `play_a.getContext()` or the way you like to refer.

Comment: Where do I put `play_a.getContext()`?

Comment: It's just an example of passing the context reference by using the View. You can even use `getBaseContext()`

Comment: Replace `this` in makeText with the suggestion